# Copy file without creating target file

Tags: php

I want to copy a file from one place to another without knowing the target file is exists or not.

**I'm using:**

```
<?php
    $source = 'user/temp/details.txt'; //this file exists.
    $target = 'user/'.$user_name.'/details.txt'; //this file don't exists.
    copy($source, $target);
?>
```

But it is saying:

```
  Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\account.php on line 3
```

Comment: You have syntax mistake `copy($source, target);` it should be `copy($source, $target);`

Comment: this mistake I created here not in my code!

Comment: Ok next do you have `'user/'.$user_name` folder created ?

Comment: yes i have used `mkdir()` for it.

Comment: 'Filename cannot be empty' means that `$source` or `$target` is empty/null, can you update your question with code including mkdir ? seem there is your mistake

Comment: I got my answer I have misspelled `temp` as `tmp` in directory name.